# What is an alternative for this slow for-loop to fill in single days between dates?

Tags: r, performance, date, for-loop, conditional-statements

For a project I'm working on, I need to have a dataframe to indicate whether a person was absent (0) or not (1) on a particular day.

The problem is: my data is in a format where it gives the starting date of absenteïsm and then the number of days the person was absent.

Example of my dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Person = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                 StartDate = c("01-01","02-01","03-01","04-01","05-01"),
                 DAYS = c(3,NA,NA,NA,1))
```

Instead of the "Start date" and "number of days absent" per person, it should look like this instead:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Person = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                 Date = c("01-01","02-01","03-01","04-01","05-01"),
                 Absent = c(1,1,1,0,1))
```

For now I solved it with this for loop with two if-conditions:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if(!is.na(df1$DAYS[i])){
     var <- df1$DAYS[i]
   }
  if(var > 0){
     var <- var-1
     df1$DAYS[i] <- 1
   }
 }
```

This works, however I have thousands of persons with a full year of dates each, meaning that I have more than 5 million rows in my dataframe. You can imagine how slow the loop is.

Does anyone know a quicker way to solve my problem?
I tried looking at the lubridate package to work with periods and dates, but I don't see a solution there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach based upon generating all the indices of observations that should be set to 1, and then filling in the values.

```r
# The data
df1 <- data.frame(Person = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  StartDate = c("01-01","02-01","03-01","04-01","05-01"),
                  DAYS = c(3,NA,NA,NA,1))

# Initialize the vector we want with zeros
df1$Absent <- 0

# we get the indices of all the non-zero day entries
inds <- which(!is.na(df1$DAYS))

# Now we are going to build a list of all the indices that should be
# set to one. These are the intervals from when absence starts to
# the number of days absent - 1
inds_to_change <- mapply(function(i,d){i:(i+d-1)}, inds, na.omit(df1$DAYS))

df1$Absent[unlist(inds_to_change)] <- 1
df1
#>   Person StartDate DAYS Absent
#> 1      1     01-01    3      1
#> 2      1     02-01   NA      1
#> 3      1     03-01   NA      1
#> 4      1     04-01   NA      0
#> 5      1     05-01    1      1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Excellent! So simple and elegant yet I probably wouldn't have figured it out myself. It now only takes a few seconds to fill the dataframe, instead of several hours. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A `data.table` alternative in a similar vein: `setDT(df1)`; `df1[ , Absent := 0]`; `df1[df1[ , {ri <- .I[!is.na(DAYS)]; rep(ri, DAYS[ri]) + sequence(DAYS[ri]) - 1}], Absent := 1]`

Answer (score 1):

A faster solution can be found by using integrated R functions.

### The general idea:

1. For each person, find the position for absent days greater than 1. Let the number of absent days be `a` and the position be `p`.
2. In every position defined by the sequence `p:(p + a - 1)` insert the value 1.
3. Return the redefined vector, in place of the old vector.

This can all be implemented into a function, and then applied across all the subgroups. For this to be faster

### the function

For the specific case using mapply (as the previous answer suggest) works, but using data.table will in general be faster for larger data sets. This is utilized below.

```
RelocateAbsentees <- function(x){
  #Find the position in x for which the value is greater than 1
  pos <- which(x > 1)
  #Fill in the vector with the absent days
  for(i in pos){
    val <- x[i]
    x[i:(i + val - 1)] <- 1
  }
  #return the vector
  pos
} 
df1 <- data.frame(Person = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  StartDate = c("01-01","02-01","03-01","04-01","05-01"),
                  DAYS = c(3,NA,NA,NA,1))
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df2 <- copy(df1)[,Person := 2]
df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)
#Using data.table package (faster)
df1[, newDays := RelocateAbsentees(DAYS), by = Person]
df3[, newDays := RelocateAbsentees(DAYS), by = Person]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Your answer seems to work as well, yet gfgm's response is a bit simpler and also only takes +- 1 second since I'm still working with a relatively small dataset. I'll keep your response and the "data.table" library in mind if I run into the same problem in larger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I found pretty neat solution using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(Abs = map_dbl(DAYS, ~ {
    if (!is.na(.x)) {
      d <<- .x
      +(d > 0)
    } else {
      d <<- d - 1
      +(d > 0)
    }
  }))
```

Comment: Whilst this might work, it's more complicated than the other answers and I'd avoid using `<<-` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your original approach was not so bad. Some minor improvements can make it faster than gfgm`s (as of my testing, I do not know your exact data structure):

```
improvedOP <- function(d) {
  days <- d$DAYS # so we do not repeatedly change data.frames column
  ii <- !is.na(days) # this can be calculated outside the loop
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
    if (ii[i]) var <- days[i]
    if (var > 0) {
      var <- var - 1
      days[i] <- 1
    }
  }
  return(days)
}
```

I came up with this approach:

```
minem <- function(d) {
  require(zoo)
  rn <- 1:nrow(d) # row numbers
  ii <- rn + d$DAYS - 1L # get row numbers which set to 1
  ii <- na.locf(ii, na.rm = F) # fill NA forward
  ii <- rn <= ii # if row number less or equal than interested row is 1
  ii[ii == 0] <- NA # set 0 to NA to match original results
  as.integer(ii)
}

all.equal(minem(d), improvedOP(d))
# TRUE
```

The idea is that we calculate row numbers which need to be 1 (current row + DAYS - 1). Then fill the NAs with this value and if row matches our condition set to 1. This should be faster than any other approach, that involves creating sequences.

Benchmark on larger (7.3 mil rows) simulated data:

```
gfgm <- function(d) {
  days <- rep(0, nrow(d))
  inds <- which(!is.na(d$DAYS))
  inds_to_change <- mapply(function(i, d) {i:(i + d - 1)}, inds, na.omit(d$DAYS))
  days[unlist(inds_to_change)] <- 1
  days
}
nrow(d)/1e6 # 7.3 mil
require(bench)
require(data.table)
bm <- bench::mark(minem(d), improvedOP(d), gfgm(d), iterations = 2, check = F)
as.data.table(bm[, 1:7])
#       expression      min     mean   median      max   itr/sec mem_alloc
# 1:      minem(d) 281.34ms 302.85ms 302.85ms 324.35ms 3.3019990     408MB
# 2: improvedOP(d) 747.45ms 754.55ms 754.55ms 761.65ms 1.3252907     139MB
# 3:       gfgm(d)    3.23s    3.27s    3.27s    3.31s 0.3056558     410MB
```

P.S. but the real results probably depends on the distribution of DAYS values.